# How do you compare and sort a specific parameter within a class?

Tags: c++, class, sorting, bubble-sort

My professor has asked us to make a program that will take a user's input and continue reading until the end of input. Only then, can the program output what the user has typed.

Input should be based on video title, it's url, comments made on the video, length (in minutes), and rating (in *).

For example:

> United Break Guitars, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v+5YGc4zOqozo, Great example of one person getting a giant company to listen, 4.5, ***, Space Versus Tabs, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SsoOG6ZeyUl, Decide for yourself: spaces or tabs?, 2.83, ****

Up until what is explained, I have completed and tested to see if everything works. My problem is the next part of the project which requires the user to choose between `Rating, Length, or title` then sort them based on what the user chose.
If I chose Rating, then the input above should be sorted from highest rated video to lowest.

This is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

#include "video.h"

int main()
{
string user, url, comment, title;
int rating;
double length;
int i = 0, last = 0;

Video *videoObj[100];
Video *temp[100];


// specifies how the videos should be sorted
cin >> user;
cin.ignore();


while (getline(cin,title)  ) {


getline(cin, url);
getline(cin, comment);
cin >> length;
cin >> rating;
cin.ignore();



videoObj[i] = new Video(title, url, comment, length, rating);
i++;
last++;
}

temp[i] = new Video(title, url, comment, length, rating);

if(user=="rating"){

    for(int i = 0; i < last - 1; i++){

for(int j = i+1; j< last; j++){

    if(videoObj[i] -> Rating(videoObj[j])) {

        temp[i] = videoObj[i];
        videoObj[i]= Rating(videoObj[j]);
        Rating(videoObj[j]) = temp[i];
      }
     }
    }
   }

for(int i= 0; i < last; i++)
{
videoObj[i]->print();

}

 //delete[] videoObj;



return 0;
}
```

video.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

#include "video.h"

Video::Video(string video_title, string video_link, string video_comment, double video_length, int video_number)
: title(video_title), link(video_link), comment(video_comment), length(video_length), rating(video_number)
{
}

bool Video::Rating(Video *videoObj) {
    if(rating > videoObj-> rating )
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}

void Video::print(){

string star;
switch(rating){

case 1:
    star = "*";
    break;
case 2:
    star = "**";
    break;
case 3:
    star = "***";
    break;
case 4:
    star = "****";
    break;
case 5:
    star = "*****";
    break;

}



 cout << title << ", " << link << ", " << comment << ", " << length << ", " << star << endl;

}



void Video::temp(){
title, link, comment, length, rating;
}
```

video.h file:

```
#ifndef VIDEO_H
#define VIDEO_H

using namespace std;

class Video {

public:
    Video(string video_title, string video_link, string video_comment, double video_length, int video_number);
    void print();
    bool Rating(Video *videoObj);
    void temp();
   

private:
    string title;
    string link;
    string comment;
    double length;
    int rating;

};


#endif
```

I honestly have no idea how to implement the bubble sort correctly. I have looked up multiple different videos on youtube and posts on stackoverflow, but I can't seem to figure out how to sort a specific parameter within my class.

My professor gave us these instructions for sorting within our class:

> When sorting the videos you need to be able to determine how two video objects should be
> ordered. The easiest way to do this is to write member functions to handle the comparisons in
> class Video. For example, this method could be used when sorting the videos by length:

```
// return true if the current video is longer than the given video (other) ,
// otherwise return false
bool Video :: longer(Video *other) {
 return (mlength > other -> mlength ;
}
```

I'm not even sure if I did that part correctly in my `video.cpp` file. Any ideas on how I can get the sorting method to work properly?
Please be gentle, I'm very new to programming. I realize my bubble sort is wrong as well, I just don't know where to start fixing it...

Comment: Unless you are forbidden to use it, you should be looking at [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) with a custom comparator.

Comment: @PaulSanders I can use any sort method I want. This was just his suggestion. I just don't know how to implement any sort method as all of this is new to me. Therefore, I thought it would be a good idea to follow his method

Comment: `std::sort` is implemented for you. Winning! All you have to do is provide a `<` operator so `std::sort` knows how to order the records.

Comment: @user4581301 I found a few examples using std::sort, but how would I specify a particular parameter within my class to sort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd normally use `std::sort` with a comparison operator for each field you want to be able to compare. You can implement those either as named classes:

```
struct by_title {
    bool operator()(Video const &a, Video const &b) { 
        return a.title < b.title;
    }
};

struct by_rating {
    bool operator()(Video const &a, Video const &b) {
        return a.rating < b.rating;
    }
};

// ...
std::sort(videos.begin(), videos.end(), by_rating);

std::sort(videos.begin(), videos.end(), by_title);
```

...or you can use a lambda expression to define a comparison:

```
// sort by rating
std::sort(videos.begin(), videos.end(), [](auto &a, auto &b) { return a.rating < b.rating; });

// sort by title
std::sort(videos.begin(), videos.end(), [](auto &a, auto &b) { return a.title < b.title; });
```

Comment: ranges version (C++20 or ranges-v3) is also convenient with the projection: `ranges::sort(videos, std::less<>{}, &Video::title);`.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin I apologize for having to ask this, but where do I put the struct? We actually haven't gotten to structs just yet. When I try to implement the code you provided, it says: "title is private" or "rating is private"